# Shift entire rows within dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame like this

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(start = rep("begin", 4),
                 x1 = rep(1, 4),
                 x2 = c(2, "begin", 2, 2),
                 x3 = c(3, 1, 3, "begin"))

  start x1    x2    x3
1 begin  1     2     3
2 begin  1 begin     1
3 begin  1     2     3
4 begin  1     2 begin
```

It's basically a wrapped version of the data frame I want, which is this one, with all the `"begin"` strings in the first column

```
df_target <- data.frame(start = rep("begin", 6),
                        x1 = c(rep(1, 5), NA),
                        x2 = c(2, NA, NA, 2, 2, NA),
                        x3 = c(3, NA, NA, 3, NA, NA))

  start x1 x2 x3
1 begin  1  2  3
2 begin  1 NA NA
3 begin  1 NA NA
4 begin  1  2  3
5 begin  1  2 NA
6 begin NA NA NA
```

I can begin to form a matrix by determining the dimensions of `df_target` based on the contents of `df`

```
num_rows <- sum(stringr::str_count(df, "begin"))
num_cols <- df %>%
  as.matrix() %>%
  as.vector() %>%
  unique() %>%
  length()
```

I don't know how to deal with putting in the correct number of `NA`s in the correct spots though.

The values in `x1`, `x2` and `x3` in my actual data set aren't as simple as 1, 2, 3 so a solution somehow based on those values isn't as helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a vector and `spilt` by the keyword *begin*. Subset this with `[` for the length of `ncol`, `transform` the column type and set the names by using `setNames`.

```
x <- c(t(df))
y <- split(x, cumsum(x == "begin"))
setNames(transform(do.call(rbind, lapply(y, "[", 1:ncol(df)))), names(df))
names(df))
#  start   x1   x2   x3
#1 begin    1    2    3
#2 begin    1 <NA> <NA>
#3 begin    1 <NA> <NA>
#4 begin    1    2    3
#5 begin    1    2 <NA>
#6 begin <NA> <NA> <NA>
```